# Does the Facebook Graph API or FQL allow you to search for photos using the new Date Tag features?

Tags: facebook, date, photo, facebook-fql

Facebook allows you  to change the date associated with a photo by clicking on that photo and clicking Change Date. However the only dates associated with a photo that are exposed through FQL are the date created and the date modified.

Created = the date that the photo was uploaded.
Modified = the date that a photo was last modified

If I change the date associated with a photo so that it is placed in a different month, year position on my timeline I want to be able to retrieve this information through FQL. Facebook does not appear to have a Date tag as one of it's photo_tag fields. For example I would like this new date that I have added to be one of the subject fields of photo_tag.

Are we able to use the facebook graph api or fql to search for this date tag that we can now add to our photos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not exposed currently via the API.  You should ask facebook to expand the API to include it.  You can put in your request at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs